# MapThread in mathematica with one variable constant

Tags: dictionary, wolfram-mathematica, fold

I would Like to fold (in order to sum) a MapThread over two lists using a function of three variabled, where the third variable is constant over the Mapthread. I would like to accomplish something like this:

```
nList = {}; For[i = 0, i <= Length[N0], i++, nSum = 0; Fold[Plus,0,MapThread[n,T,M,N0[i]]]];
```

where n is such that n[t_,m_,n0_] 
I could make a list N0' of Length[T] and fill it with N0[i] but that's a bit of a hack. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I want to be helpful but I find this question hard to read.  Would you please make attempt to make it a bit more readable, and give a simple example of the input and output you desire?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is syntactically incorrect; the `MapThread` accepts only 3 arguments.

Instead of the `For` loop try

```
   Plus@@MapThread[n[#1,#2,N0]&,{T,M}]
```

1. Idiom `Plus@@`(...) produces sum of the given list (it applies `Plus` to the list)
2. Mathematica is very strong with its lambda expressions, i.e. nameless functions. For convenience it has very short notation for it: every argument you substitute with the placeholder `#1`, `#2`, `#3`,... and after the function body you designate it is a nameless function with `&` sign. Equivalently you could write `Function[{t,m},n[t,m,N0]]` instead of `n[#1,#2,No]&`. See help for `Function`.